# How to copy files over ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

How do I copy a file using ssh from my test server to my production server, how do I do this for a single file and how do I do this for multiple files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**From Window to Linux**

Download https://cygwin.com/ this will give you a proper terminal which will then allow you to run the linux commands as listed below in the From Linux to Linux section.

**From Linux to Linux**

The essential command is this

**The command**

scp [ssh login to remote server]:[filepath] [local filepath]

**To copy a single file example**

```
scp user@your.server.example.com:/path/to/foo/[filename] /home/user/Desktop/[filename]
```

**To copy a directory example**

```
scp -r user@your.server.example.com:/path/to/foo /home/user/Desktop/
```

**To use full power of scp you need to go through next steps:**

1. [Setup public key authentication](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2)
2. [Create ssh aliases](http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/)

Then, for example if you'll have this ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host test
    User testuser
    HostName test-site.com
    Port 22022

Host prod
    User produser
    HostName production-site.com
    Port 22022
```

you'll save yourself from password entry and simplify scp syntax like this:

```
scp -r prod:/path/foo /home/user/Desktop   # copy to local
scp -r prod:/path/foo test:/tmp            # copy from remote prod to remote test
```

More over, you will be able to use remote path-completion:

```
scp test:/var/log/  # press tab twice
Display all 151 possibilities? (y or n)
```